# Run a Python script after CSV has been created within same VBScript?

Tags: python, vbscript

```vb
Set lstArgs = WScript.Arguments
For I = 0 To lstArgs.Count - 1 ' Loop through each file
    FullName = lstArgs(I)
    FileName = Left(lstArgs(I), InStrRev(lstArgs(I), ".") )

    'Create Excel Objects
    MyPath = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, Len(WScript.ScriptFullName) - Len(WScript.ScriptName))
    Set objWS = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    Set objWB = objWS.Workbooks.Open(FullName)
    Set oVBC = objWB.VBProject.VBComponents
    oVBC.Import (MyPath & "LIS.bas")
    objWB.Application.Run "LIS2CSV"
    objWS.Application.Visible = False
    objWS.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'MsgBox FileName
    objWB.SaveAs FileName & "csv", 23
    objWB.SaveAs
    objWS.Application.Quit
    objWS.Quit

    'Destroy Excel Objects
    Set objWS = Nothing
    Set objWB = Nothing
Next
```

The above code works.  I can take a file of type ".lis", drag it on to the VBScript and drop.  Out pops a .csv file all nice and clean.

I have a Python script that will come along and collect all the CSV files and perform magic tricks with them, returning formatted .xlsx files.  This also works.

How may I patch these two processes together?  *May* I patch these two processes together?

Comment: Your VBScript already uses an Excel COM object. What would you need an additional Python script for? You should be able to do all processing/formatting including saving .xlsx files from your VBScript.

Comment: Honestly, I will have to pursue what you've given to provide a sound answer.  I have some experience in Python, none in VBScript.  What you see is a Frankenstein's Monster of a script built from scrounging bits and pieces off the web and forcing it to work.  That said, I do appreciate the information, I'll get back to you with an answer!